# Mozilla Addon SDK - Problem with Reddit example on 2nd page

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I got this problem during development of my own addon, but I get the same with the reddit example, so I'll use that for simplicity.

Using the exact code from the example found [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html), this is what happens.

> Reddit Example
>
> This example add-on creates a panel containing the mobile version of Reddit. When the user clicks on the title of a story in the panel, the add-on opens the linked story in a new tab in the main browser window.
>
> To accomplish this the add-on needs to run a content script in the context of the Reddit page which intercepts mouse clicks on each title link and fetches the link's target URL. The content script then needs to send the URL to the add-on script.

main.js:

```
var data = require("self").data;

var reddit_panel = require("panel").Panel({
  width: 240,
  height: 320,
  contentURL: "http://www.reddit.com/.mobile?keep_extension=True",
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.4.4.min.js"),
                  data.url("panel.js")]
});

reddit_panel.port.on("click", function(url) {
  require("tabs").open(url);
});

require("widget").Widget({
  id: "open-reddit-btn",
  label: "Reddit",
  contentURL: "http://www.reddit.com/static/favicon.ico",
  panel: reddit_panel
});
```

panel.js:

```
$(window).click(function (event) {
  var t = event.target;

  // Don't intercept the click if it isn't on a link.
  if (t.nodeName != "A")
    return;

  // Don't intercept the click if it was on one of the links in the header
  // or next/previous footer, since those links should load in the panel itself.
  if ($(t).parents('#header').length || $(t).parents('.nextprev').length)
    return;

  // Intercept the click, passing it to the addon, which will load it in a tab.
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  self.port.emit('click', t.toString());
});
```

The icon is displayed in the bar, and clicking it launches the panel. Clicking a link within the panel opens it in a new tab - just as described and expected.

Clicking the "next page" link within the tab successfully fetches the next page, within the panel - as expected.

Clicking a link on the 2nd page does NOT open it in a tab, it opens it WITHIN the panel.

Here's my guess: When the page reloads within the panel, it does not reload the script specified in the `contentScriptFile`. Does anyone else experience this? And is there a workaround?

I'm using SDK 1.0 and FF 5.0

Question cross-posted on the Addon forum [here](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=3587)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recieved [this answer](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=3587&p=11003#p10998) at the Mozilla forum, and will post here as well for future reference.

> Perhaps you are seeing [Bug 667664 - Panel content scripts don't work after reloading or changing location](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=667664). I think the workaround is to load the content in an iframe.

Which I believe might be the case, I'll try this during the day and report back.

**EDIT:** iframe seems to do the trick